# Split string into groups of 3 characters

Tags: python, string, list

I have a string

```
ddffjh3gs
```

I want to convert it into a list

```
["ddf", "fjh", "3gs"]
```

In groups of 3 characters as seen above.
What is the best way to do this in python 2.7?

Comment: In the original string, `f` appears once. But in a list, there are two. Why?

Comment: falsetru mistake, fixing...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) with string slice:

```
>>> s = 'ddffjh3gs'
>>> [s[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(s), 3)]
['ddf', 'fjh', '3gs']
```

Comment: thank you, I love the shorthand

Comment: how get something like ['ddf', 'dff', 'ffj','fjh','jh3','h3g','3gs']

Comment: @Basudev, `[s[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(s)-2)]`